# Changing the text of a C++ CLI label

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, label

I am trying to change the text of a label in a C++ CLI program. I need to take a value the the user entered in a textbox, insert that into a short string, then change a label to that string. I have no problem constructing the string, but I am having trouble setting the label to the new string. Here is my code...

```
std::string v1str = "Phase A: ";
v1str.append(vt2); //vt2 is type str::string
v1str.append(" Vac");
label->Text = v1str;
```

This is the error message that I'm getting...

[image]

Why am I not allowed to pass `v1str` as the label text setter? How can I pass the string I've constructed to the label text setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Label::Text` has a type of `System::String^`, which is a managed .Net string object.  You cannot assign a `std:string` to a `System::String^` directly becuase they are different types.

You can [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx) a `std::string` to a `System::String`.  However you most likely just want to use the `System::String` type directly:

```
System::String^ v1str = "Phase A: ";
v1st += vt2; // or maybe gcnew System::String(vt2.c_str());
v1str += " Vac";
label->Text = v1str;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I actually made one change to the above code. vt2 was of the type `str::string` which could not be concatenated with `System::String^ v1str`. Luckily, vt2 was created from the original text entered in the textbox (of the form `System::String^`) to make sure that it was a proper input so I was able to use `textbox->Text` in place of `vt2` in your above code to solve my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI is not C++, you can't use `std::string` in there. But you can use C++ within C++/CLI, and convert `std::string` to and from `System::String`

```
//In C++/CLI form: 
#include <vcclr.h>

System::String^ clr_sting = "clr_sting";

//convert strings from CLI to C++
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> cpp_string = PtrToStringChars(clr_sting);

//convert strings from C++ to CLI
System::String^ str = gcnew System::String(cpp_string);

//or
std::string std_string = "std_string";
System::String^ str2 = gcnew System::String(std_string.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using @shf301 answer to solve my problem, but this is my first time using CLI and this comment helped clear up a lot of the confusion I've been having.